# Converting tabs into dropdown menu (not select)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently using Bootstrap to create tabs and the task is for mobile screen (800px <), it should automatically change into a "fake" dropdown. When i say fake, i mean no select box but utilising the the same `ul` as the tabs, it should automatically use the first item as a trigger.

**I can get the tabs working fine**: https://codepen.io/wizly/pen/BlKxo

**What do i want to achieve?**

On mobile view, when the tabs are in more of a dropdown format, i want to try and get the label for the active tab right at the top of the list.

Scenario: **Mobile View Default**

```
[ITEM 1 active >]
```

Scenario: **Mobile view Clicked**

```
[ITEM 1]
[ITEM 2]
[ITEM 3]
```

Scenario: **Mobile view item 3 clicked**

```
[ITEM 3 active >]
```

Scenario: **Mobile view item 3 active clicked**

```
[ITEM 1]
[ITEM 2]
[ITEM 3]
```

**Where am i so far**:

```js
  $('li a').on('click', function() {
        const current = $(this);
        const ul = current.parent().parent();
        const li = current.parent();

        if ($(window).width() < 1023.98) {
            ul.toggleClass('expanded');
            $('li').removeClass('active');
            $('.fake-active').removeClass('fake-active');

            if (ul.hasClass('expanded')) {
                $('li').removeClass('active');
                current.addClass('fake-active');
            }

            li.toggleClass('active');
            // ul.prepend(current.parent());
        }
    });
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
body {
  padding: 10px;
}

#exTab2 h3 {
  color: white;
  background-color: #428bca;
  padding: 5px 15px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  ul li {
    display: block !important;
    float: none !important;
  }
  ul li:first-child a {
    text-align: left !important;
  }
  ul li:first-child a:after {
    font-family: fontello;
    content: "";
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    line-height: 1;
    min-width: 1em;
    margin-left: 1em;
    text-decoration: inherit;
    text-transform: none;
    float: right;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
  ul li:not(:first-child) {
    display: none !important;
  }
  ul.expanded li:not(:first-child) {
    display: block !important;
  }
  ul.expanded li:not(:first-child) a {
    text-align: left !important;
  }
  ul.expanded li:first-child a:after {
    content: "";
    transform: rotate(270deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="exTab2" class="container">
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active">
   <a href="#1" data-toggle="tab">Overview</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#2" data-toggle="tab">Without clearfix</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#3" data-toggle="tab">Solution</a>
  </li>
 </ul>

 <div class="tab-content ">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="1">
   <h3>Standard tab panel created on bootstrap using nav-tabs</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="2">
   <h3>Notice the gap between the content and tab after applying a background color</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="3">
   <h3>add clearfix to tab-content (see the css)</h3>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it might be too late...

based on your source code, i used .active instead of :first-child for css selector and changed JS a little, and it seems work properly.

here's the codepen https://codepen.io/lebniz/pen/zYdLXxJ

js:

```
$("li a").on("click", function () {
  const current = $(this);
  const ul = current.parent().parent();
  let tab_id = current.attr("href");

  if ($(window).width() < 1023.98) {
    $(tab_id).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
    ul.toggleClass("expanded");
  }
});
```